Why can I not see the “Create Folder” option in Power BI workspaces?
I'm trying to create subfolders within a PowerBI workspace, which I'm tracking was released back in March 2024.
Allegedly, I'm an admin for our tenant but I'm not seeing this as an option. According to the documentation, I should see "Folder" as an option under "New".
However, I don't have that as an option. Also, I'm allegedly an admin on the tenant.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have screenshots, but I'm not able to post them in a question apparently. Power BI allegedly has the functionality of creating folders within a workspace. I cannot see it. I'm also on a government tenant but I don't know if that matters for such a feature.
